# How can I discover if two files have the same permissions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I discover if two given files have the same permissions in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare files' [permission bits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-mode).

```
File.stat(a).mode % 01000 == File.stat(b).mode % 01000
```

where `a` and `b` are filenames. Use modulo octal 1000 to remove additional information about the node, i.e. whether it's a file or directory, whether it has a sticky bit, etc.